# Asymptotics of sum of Chebychev function

Tags: summation, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, chebyshev-function

Show that $\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{θ(n)}{n^2}=\ln x+O(1)$ where $θ$ is the Chebychev function. (We are searching for a solution without the prime number theorem, just Chebychev bounds or something like that, but the exercise is talking about a solution without the PNT.)

First my thought was to maybe use Shapiro for the fucntion $θ(n)/n$, but it doesn't seem to work.

Then I thought to use Shapiro together with the fact that $\sum_{n\leq x}θ(x/n)=x\log x+O(x)$ or the fact that $\sum_{n\leq x}ψ(x/n)=x\log x+O(x)$ so as to bring $\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{θ(n)[x/n]}{n}$ close to one of the 2 last sums (like minus $O(x)$ or $O(1)$) and then use Shapiro, but I cant find something clear. Any ideas, suggestions?

Comment: Do you already know the prime number theorem asymptotic for $\theta(n)$? Plugging that in should solve the problem immediately. If not, note that $\displaystyle\sum_{n\le x} \frac{\theta(n)}{n^2} = \sum_{n\le x} \frac1{n^2} \sum_{p\le n} \log p = \sum_{p\le x} \log p \sum_{n\in[p,x]} \frac1{n^2}$....

Comment: I am sorry i should have explained...I am searching for a solution without prime number theorem , i will edit it .... sorry. But by the way could we prove that by use just chebychev bounds or something like that?

Comment: @GregMartin what follows at the end of your comment after '...' ???

Comment: Estimate that sum by the integral $\int_p^x \frac1{t^2}\,dt$.

Answer (score 1):

- $\sum_{p\in (n,2n]} \log p \le \log {2n\choose n}=O(n)$ gives that $\sum_{p^k\le n} \log p =O(n)$
- So $n \log n +O(n)= \log n! = \sum_{p^k\le n} \lfloor n/p^k \rfloor \log p=
  \sum_{p^k\le n} \frac{n }{ p^k}\log p +O(n)$ $=
  \sum_{p\le n} \frac{n }{ p}\log p+O(n)$
- With a partial summation we get $O(1)+\log x=\sum_{p\le x}\frac{\log p}p=
  \frac{\theta(n)}n+\sum_{n\le x-1}\theta(n)(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1})=
  O(1)+\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\theta(n)}{n^2}$

Comment: what partial summation?

Comment: Try and see what you get

Comment: I dont see what do you partial summate... Where do you mean  to do partial summation?

Comment: $\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{θ(n)}{n^2}=O(1)+\sum_{p\le x}\frac{\log p}p$

Comment: my friend, it makes no sense to me. please explain further. partial summate what exactly!? this is partial summation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts , or even thta https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula . But i dont get what you want to say at all. Could you please write it more analytically?

Answer (score 0):

This is just an expanded account of the method suggested by Greg Martin:

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n\le x}{\vartheta(n)\over n^2}
&=\sum_{n\le x}{1\over n^2}\sum_{p\le n}\log p=\sum_{p\le x}\log p\sum_{p\le n\le x}{1\over n^2} \\
&=\sum_{p\le x}\log p\left\{\int_p^x{\mathrm dt\over t^2}+O\left(1\over p^2\right)\right\} \\
&=\sum_{p\le x}{\log p\over p}+O\left\{\sum_{p\le x}{\log p\over p^2}\right\}+O\left\{\frac1x\sum_{p\le x}\log p\right\} \\
&=\sum_{p\le x}{\log p\over p}+O(1)=\log x+O(1),
\end{aligned}

wherein the second last inequality follows from Chebyshev's bound, and the last equality follows from Mertens' first theorem.

Comment: How did you estimate $- \frac{1}{x}\sum_{p \le x} {\log p}$ after computing the integral?

Comment: @Gary Chebyshev's upper estimate $\vartheta(x)=O(x)$ suffices.

Comment: Just a question, what exactly $O(1/p^2)$ means?I know the asymptotics type for the sum of $1/n^2$ , and I know it occurs from there, but what exactly that means and how we use it in the sum so as to take it out of the sum in that way?

Comment: it just means the term is bounded by a constant (which depends on neither $p$ nor $x$) multiple of $1/p^2$.